# How to make IFRAME work with IE 11 where a XSL is launching a JSP in an IFRAME?

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer, xslt, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I have a query regarding IFRAME used in IE 11. I have a web application that works fine in all the browser except IE 11. It works fine with version IE 10 and below. There is a parent page [XSL} which hosts another JSP into an IFRAME. In IE 11 , it shows "Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate." where as in other browsers the content is displayed in an iframe.
Further more with the research, the jsp that is called within the iframe uses https protocol.
I tested it with http protocol it works fine. But with https , it breaks.
What should I do to fix the issue of "Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate. " due to IFRAME in IE 11.

Comment: Any suggestions by anyone

Comment: What happens if you try to load the iframe content directly in an IE 11browser window, does IE 11 then also signal that security problem?

Comment: have you tried this http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-fix-content-was-blocked-because-it-was-not-signed-by-a-valid-security-certificate-on-internet-explorer/

Comment: Hi Martin Honnen, If I try to load the iframe content directly, it works fine. and also no security problem

Comment: @Roman  I have tried all these steps

Comment: anymore suggestions?